# Object does not exist at path warning and QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, networking, network-programming, qt5

I noticed that if I create an instance of `QNetworkAccessManager` and even do not use the instance -- not making any requests or something -- and then I turn off my VPN, my Qt Application prints:

```
"Object does not exist at path “/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/28”"
"Object does not exist at path “/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/28”"
```

It looks like it's not my fault. But is there any way to get rid of the warnings? Or am I doing anything wrong?

The only way I can imagine is to create an instance of `QNetworkAccessManager` on each actual request. But this sounds really inefficient. Also, what if I switch off my VPN during the actual request -- then I still will end up with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a QT bug https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-114666 which has different symptoms, but the description is accurate to what is happening here.

Fortunately there is a fix for it, that can be found in comments to this bug https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/373426, so applying this patch resolves the issue.

When doing so, the warning is gone in my project and it seems that it should work from the change being done. One additional note that on my project I also observed a lot of CPU time spent in the `QNetworkManager` and this patch also resolved this issue as well.

Note: this might depend on the version of NetworkManager being used, as the new interface was only introduced in 1.2.0 (You can see `PropertiesChanged` signal description here https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active.html), while my version is 1.42.6 (you can check the version you are using via `nmcli --version`)